# is it is possible to make scroll an picturebox on keypress in vb.net2008

Tags: vb.net

i have an picturebox and textarea in an panel i need to scroll the picture box image on keypress down arrow  >..

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.PreviewKeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then 
       ' Scrolling Code
    End If
End Sub
```

You can handle a picture box keydown like this.